# My skype doesn't login on my Lumia 535.

Tags: skype

I am using skype over my phone Lumia 535, I logged out one day, And then it doesn't Login again It gives this error which says "Oops, Please check your network settings and try again". now i have checked all the setting and other applications are running very much perfectly except skype. Please tell me how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Skype for Windows phone](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-windows-phone/) website on your Lumia 535 and check if your Skype version is up to date. If Skype isn't up to date install the latest version.